# Transiting Budapest Airport in Times of COVID

Tags: transit, airports, hungary, budapest, bud

I'm supposed to fly from BUD to the US at the end of the month. Due to COVID restrictions, as a US citizen, I can't enter Hungary; however, according to the BUD airport website and various government websites, I **can** transit BUD if I show proof of onward travel as long as it's within 24 hours. I would appreciate some advice/guidance on my plan:

In order to remain in the transit area and stay airside, I've booked a separate ticket from Paris to BUD, and I'd arrive late at night. I'd spend less than 7 hours in BUD before catching my flight to the US (via Paris) the next morning. Is this permitted? (I'm worried about being denied boarding on my evening flight to BUD from Paris.) The BUD airport website seems to suggest that transit passengers (who are non-Hungarian citizens) can stay airside and they provide blankets, cots, and wifi before catching their next flight, and I seem to fulfill all the requirements listed.

Comment: With the US now on the EU "white list," I wonder how this will affect entry into Hungary within the Schengen zone.

Comment: Things are changing rapidly, it's hard to know what'll be the state of affairs in two weeks. Make you you don't have checked luggage because you can't stay airside if you have two different tickets and need to collect your luggage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will be able to transit via Budapest Airport IF you comply with Government Directive 408/2020 (VIII.30) which permits you to stay airside in case you subject yourself to a medical examination and are found to test negative for Covid-19 AND your entry into the US is guaranteed (which it would be since you are a USC). However, also check the rules for transitting in Paris.